# ASP.NET: Get rid of "&nbsp;" in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

So I am currently getting a format-error (and rightfully so), because of this value. I think it is some sort of unicode space-alternative or something.

This is how I call the value:

```
int updatecount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text);
```

This is the value while debugging:
[image]

I need the value to be numeric OR null. Did anyone have similar problems?

**UPDATE:**
This is how I assigned the value:

CODE BEFORE
[image]

```
<asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="BASKET_ID" DataFormatString="" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vertrags-Beginn">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="STARTINGDATE"  Text='<%# ((DateTime)(Eval("CONTRACT_POS_START"))).ToShortDateString() %>'>
        </asp:TextBox><ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" ID="startingdatecalendar" TargetControlID="STARTINGDATE" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Anzahl Tage" DataField="DAYCOUNT"  />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
Basket_Grid.DataSource = cdbe.VwBaskets.ToList();
Basket_Grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: How do you assign the value there? Plus: you can't really render `null` to the client, it doesn't make sense in a browser.

Comment: The null doesn't matter in the front end. I am allowing it, because the textbox is only visible under a specific condition. Therefore it makes sense, because my database does then know, that the field was never even shown.

Comment: This might seem nuts but I've seen something like this before: try putting the closing textbox tag on the same line as the opening tag. The new line might be adding a space. Hth.

Comment: I now changed the markup to this (I believe @wazz, u ment something like this):
`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="STARTINGDATE"  Text='<%# ((DateTime)(Eval("CONTRACT_POS_START"))).ToShortDateString() %>'></asp:TextBox><ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" ID="startingdatecalendar" TargetControlID="STARTINGDATE" />`
Didn't help though - still - thanks!

Comment: Too bad. I've seen line breaks break things, but maybe that's in the past now.

Comment: Wondering if you have to cast to DateTime; you're doing `ToShortDateString` so it might not be necessary...?

Comment: I just realized I was looking at the wrong cell. Which cell are you trying to get? There are 3 in the image, and 2 in the code.

Comment: @wazz Yes, the `ToShortDateString` is necessary. The client wishes the date to be formatted like this. I have tried to just format it as a `DateTime` value but for proof of concept reasons, didn't change the output.
It's about the `DAYCOUNT` BoundField. You're right, thx, will just add the line to the question.

Comment: And the problem is *not* with the date cell but the DAYCOUNT, which is cell[2]? If so, then go back to the very first comment by @WiktorZychla.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172199/discussion-between-phils-instrumentals-and-wazz).

Comment: Just need an answer to that one question.

Comment: I did - I updated the question as to how I apply the value and how the `null` is making sense on the page... - See second comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
int updatecount = ( IsNumeric(String.row.Cells[2].Text) ? Convert.ToInt32(String.row.Cells[2].Text) : 0 );
```

Answer (score 3):

try HtmlDecode

> It will convert  string that has been HTML-encoded for html
>   transmission into decoded string.

```
int updatecount = Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text));
```

Or

```
 int updatecount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
```